# Build release abb without null safety

Tags: android, flutter

I try to build a singed abb for my flutter project to upload on google play console but I want to do that with android studio, but the problem is that when I open the android project I can't see any `additional args` option on configurations to run it without null safety. I tried to build the abb file from the command line with this command (`flutter build appbundle --release --no-sound-null-safety`
) but I'm getting this error from the google play console:

```
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Learn more about signing.
```

Comment: Do as it says:  ***Learn more about signing***

Comment: If you follow the instructions at https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app the resulting app bundle file should be signed as needed ✌️